# What Pathfinder creature most accurately fits Hexxus from Ferngully?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The story arc that my campaign is following is going to lead the party into an encounter with a malevolent being that I'm completely ripping off of Hexxus from Ferngully. Hexxus is a terrifyingly powerful creature that feeds off of pollution and destruction. In the film he starts out as a tiny tarry ooze like creature, but with a food source he quickly grows into a gargantuan cloud of toxic waste. I'd like to use an existing creature from within the Pathfinder bestiary to represent him (at least in his full toxic cloud form), though I'm open to third party sources. So far, I haven't had any success in identifying an appropriate match.

I've been focusing my search on demons, since their chaotic nature and love of destruction fits the context of the story perfectly. The best fit I've found on my own is an Omox demon. It's not a great fit for Hexxus, as Omoxes tend to favor rot and decay more than pollution (a minor distinction, I know), and this party has already faced an Omox before and I don't want to get repetitive.

The party is a group of 6 at level 10. The CR of the target creature doesn't have to be an exact match, but it should be close. I can always invent a new creature, but I'm a relatively new GM and it would certainly be poorly balanced.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see... Our Monster...

> feeds off of pollution and destruction [...] starts out as a tiny tarry ooze like creature [...] [and] quickly grows into a gargantuan cloud of toxic waste.

Now, this pretty much screams abberation, even better, the description even says clearly it is an [ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes) for the early shape. And, this might still hold true for the mist/fog of the adult phase, as you'll see in a bit.

### Hatchlings (CR 2-4)

One of the better matches for a 'toxic' base ooze living in caustic environments might be the [Slime Mold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/mold-slime), [Mudbog](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/mudbog), [Mercury Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-mercury) and [Gray Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-gray) at CR2 to CR3 or 4, representing "hatchlings", but other CR2-4 oozes make equally well, if just reskinned a tad and possibly just add strengths in numbers: many many cute oozes!

### Young (CR 6)

As they grow, they might 'evolve' into the CR6 [Id Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-gray/ooze-id) variant of the [Gray Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-gray), or a [Roiling Oil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/roiling-oil), depending on it's diet (flameable vs. caustic stuff). Or we grab a monster that I will explore a bit below: Hungry Fog (link follows in Monster Buffing)

### really Adult Monster (CR 10-15 + environment)

When it reaches adulthood, or close to it, it might be better represented by a CR 11 [Putrid Ooze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/ooze-putrid), CR13 [Bog Scum](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/bog-scum) or CR 15 [Riftcreeper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/riftcreeper), but these are all still "solid" enemies, that might need to be either re-fluffed to represent the mist or they just represent the "herart/core" of the being, and the easily passable surroundings of the caustic fog are then represented by making the whole area filled with some [environmental hazard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules) like acid gas or lack of oxygen (suffocation), demanding fort-saves and eating away the armor. This however would clearly increase the challenge by at least one or two ranks, possibly even more, so this sounds more like a really old monster, fitting either as the ultimate boss battle or a group of lvl 10 heroes. But didn't I mention fog & mist earlier? Yes, and here's why:

### Monster Buffing of the Hungry Fog (Cr6 + Templates)

There is also an already gaseous ooze: The CR 6 [Hungry Fog](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/hungry-fog) might represent the being in some state between the CR11+ of the block above (including a toxic environment). However, a 6 seems a bit underwhelmed for a 'young adult' monster, so we better start amping it up. Let's start by adding [monster templates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates), that is after all the easy way: Let's start with [Advanced](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1) to amp it to CR 7. And even if it is not a real swarm, adding the [Apocalypse Swarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/apocalypse-swarm-cr-3) template will beef our toxic mist monster up to 10 in a very fitting way, evenm if it is not of [swarm subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-swarm) (which I personally wouldn't bother adding via the [swarm template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/creature-swarm-template), too much trouble). Just taking the Apocalypse Swarm, have cutting through it mostly create more monsters, allow it to fix itself and allow split of parts to remerge (which is not stated in either template, but would make sense) as a move action might allow you to tailor the final showdown.

And again, you could add tons of toxic pits to its lair for an increased CR. Or stack another template, just to tip the scales.

---

The CR 7 Advanced Hungry Fog has roughly the following stats:

- AC 9, 73 HP
- Attack +7 touch (6d6+2 negative energy damage)
- DC10 will save vs. fear (shaken or nothing)

The CR 10 Advanced, Apocalypse Swarm Hungry Fog adds or changes several abilities, most notably:

- charisma based Fear aura in 100 ft (DC 10 will save, remember: that makes two DC10 checks, one for the aura and one for the Bewitching Brume from the base!).
- a nauseating "distraction" effect in it's area (DC 22)
- 126 HP (12d8+12*6); fast healing 10; Spell resistance 17
- AC 11

Even as it is not stated, I would rule that if two pieces of our CR10 Hungry Fog are adjacent, they may merge as a free action